# Input vector to a symbolic system of functions

Tags: function, matlab, system, equation

Suppose that I have written a function containing 3 separable functions(a system of equations).
I want to calculate the value of this function for 3 different values of my variables but I do not want to use "subs" function. What I want to do is enter a vector containing the desired values of my variables and calculate the main function which is a vector. How could I do that?. Notice that I do not want to call the function by each variable. Here is my code:

```
syms x y z
f1 = symfun(x.^2+3.*x.*y,[x,y,z]);
f2 = symfun(z.^3+y-x.^3-12,[x,y,z]);
f3 = symfun(2*z+x.*y+z.*x+1,[x,y,z]);

f = [f1;f2;f3];
```

What I mean is to calculate the `f` function by for example: `f([12 4 6])` not by`f(12 4 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant, but the best I could think of at the moment is to put it in a function wrapper. This might be one way to pass inputs as an array. This will bridge the gap between indexing the array input to be passed into the `symfcn` (symbolic functions).

```
f([12 4 6])


function [Results] = f(Inputs)
syms x y z
f1(x,y,z) = x.^2+3.*x.*y;
f2(x,y,z) = z.^3+y-x.^3-12;
f3(x,y,z) = 2*z+x.*y+z.*x+1;

Sym_Functions = [f1;f2;f3];
Results = Sym_Functions(Inputs(1),Inputs(2),Inputs(3));
end
```

Comment: or inline: `g = @(x) f(x(1), x(2), x(3));`